# passing anchor through $_GET without javascript

Tags: php, html

I have a page with phone numbers organized by topic and by country. Country is a $_GET value, topic is an anchor. On another page I need users to select their topic from a dropdown menu (e.g. "techsupport") and their country from a row of buttons (e.g. "US"), and be taken to the corresponding section of my page (e.g. "page.php?country=US#techsupport). I can't use javascript, so I'm guessing my only option is to pass both parameters as $_GET and then redirect the page to itself. Thought I'd ask if there's a better way around. Thank you very much!

Comment: I you can't use JavaScript, then the only option is a redirect. Though, I wonder what is the reason for that JS restriction.

Comment: @tereško homework maybe?

Comment: @julekgwa I actually suspect something more along the lines of "governmental work".

Comment: Thank you for answering tereško! It's a health/wellness non-profit, the form has to be accessible to those who have JS disabled; plus it will also be iframe'd on third party sites. I'll do a redirect, thanks for confirming my suspicion that it's the only way around.